# If $\tau_n$ equals $\tau$ eventually then $P(\tau_n \neq \tau) < \delta/2$ for any $\delta>0$ for large enough $n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\tau_n, \tau$ be random variables on a probability space $\Omega$ such that $\tau_n(\omega) =\tau(\omega)$ eventually.

In this case, how can we prove that for any $\delta>0$, there is a $N$ large enough such that, we have $P(\tau_N \neq \tau) < \delta/2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n := \{ \omega : \tau_N(\omega) \ne \tau(\omega) \text{ for some } N \ge n\}$.  By hypothesis, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset$.  Note that $A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}$, so by the monotone convergence theorem for sets, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = 0$.  Hence we conclude that for all $\delta$ there exists $N$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_N) \le \frac{\delta}{2}$.  Therefore $\mathbb{P}(\tau_N \ne \tau) \le \mathbb{P}(A_N) \le \frac{\delta}{2}$ as desired.

As pointed out in the comments, we need $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_{n}$ for this proof to work.  This is why we defined $A_n := \{ \omega : \tau_N(\omega) \ne \tau(\omega) \text{ for some } N \ge n\}$ instead of just $\{ \omega : \tau_n(\omega) \ne \tau(\omega)\}$.

Comment: Add the comment that $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ to display why "monotone" convergence can be used.

Comment: @GEdgar Added, and elaborated on that being the reason for defining $A_n$ in this way.